# Loading Android Kernel modules

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel-module

After weeks of mucking around i have (i think) successfully compiled g_hid.ko (USB Gadget HID module) for my Samsung Galaxy S3 but have been unable to test it. If i try and use insmod from the directory it is stored in i get `insmod: can't insert 'g_hid.ko': No such device` I'm new to this but i think this means that i should have loaded something else that g_hid is dependent on first. Any one know what this would be or how i can find out?

Also when trying to use rmmod i receive the following error `rmmod: chdir(/system/lib/modules): No such file or directory` which is true, that directory doesnt exist, as far as i can tell, my modules are stored in /lib/modules but this is a read only file system so i cant add my modle there. I also get the same error if i try and use modprobe. Any help you can offer would be greatly appreiated.

Thanks

Adrian

Comment: This would perhaps be better suited for http://www.xda-developers.com

Comment: Thanks, ill see if they can help

Comment: maybe you need to "root" your device first? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually got this to work. The continual discussion on the topic is at [Is it possible to program Android to act as physical USB keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805731/is-it-possible-to-program-android-to-act-as-physical-usb-keyboard/12633592) and http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1871281 When i have some free time in a few weeks (after uni) i intend to write up how i did every thing as there appears to be a lot of interest.

Comment: Sorry, I never got around to the detailed writeup. I haven't done anything with this since I got it working 2 years ago and don't remember exact details on how to use it. Your best bet is to check out the XDA link above as I wrote up most of it there (although that was more focused on getting it to compile). Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the inability to place the module into system/lib/modules...  You must first connect to the device and issue the commands:
  adb root
  adb remount

After issuing these commands you can place your .ko into the correct directory and the "read only file system" problem will go away.