# Emulating/Spoofing a USB HID Device with an Android without custom firmware or hardware

Tags: android, keyboard, usb, hid, android-firmware

I know a similar question has been asked here: [Is it possible to program Android to act as physical USB keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805731/is-it-possible-to-program-android-to-act-as-physical-usb-keyboard) However, I would love to know if there's a possible way to create a USB Human Interface Device WITHOUT requiring the target device to flash custom firmware or external hardware devices. Could I perhaps modify firmware through code to allow for HID? Basically I'm wondering if there's a way to do this where on the user's side they only need to download and run an app.

Comment: "Could I perhaps modify firmware through code to allow for HID? " -- fortunately, no, for obvious security reasons, except perhaps on a rooted device.

Comment: How would this be done on a rooted device?