# Android - Bluetooth Low Energy Remote Keyboard & Mouse

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Planning to develop an Android app that allows users to remotely control their keyboard and mouse via bluetooth. I have seen a few apps that utilize the user's home network but would like to learn some bluetooth structure. This is also going to be one of my first projects in Android and will help me learn to use the Android-SDK.

Would it be reasonable to use a Bluetooth LowEnergy connection (BLE)? I dont really understand how the [differences](http://www.medicalelectronicsdesign.com/article/bluetooth-low-energy-vs-classic-bluetooth-choose-best-wireless-technology-your-application) of *data payload throughput* will impact the tracking and communicating of key-presses and mouse events.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware of the different roles in BLE. In a regular BLE keyboard or mouse, the device would be what's called a Peripheral, and the PC would be a Central. A Central can connect to a Peripheral, but a Peripheral can not connect directly with another Peripheral, or Central to Central. However, the PC would also be a GATT Client, to the data contained in the GATT Server on the device. You can read more about roles and data transfer in BLE [here](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/index.php/what-is-a-client-and-server-in-ble) and [here](https://bluegiga.zendesk.com/entries/25053373--REFERENCE-BLE-master-slave-GATT-client-server-and-data-RX-TX-basics).

However, the most important point is that Android currently only exposes APIs to be a Central, and it is hence impossible for a PC to connect to such device. This means that it will not be possible to implement your application using Bluetooth low energy.

Comment: There is a small exception: There is a new API that allows an Android device to appear as a Peripheral. The API does work on Nexus 6 and 9 devices. [Reference](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1570)